# Javascript processes already running then wait

Tags: javascript, process

I can't get a function to work. It should check if Iexplore.exe is running, if it's running then wait. If not then run the Script.

I'm not sure how to add wait function in.

```
function main() {
var ieinfostate = false;
var iewait = setInterval(function () {
if (ProcessesRunning("iexplore.exe") != 1) {
    clearInterval(iewait);
    dosomethingelse();
} else if (ieinfostate == false) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using jscript, there is a sleep() method. thought.. thats the worst you could use since javascript is designed to be async.

you could do it like this:

```
var ieinfostate = false;

var iewait = setInterval(function () {
    if (ProcessesRunning("iexplore.exe") != 1) {
        clearInterval(iewait);
        dosomethingelse();
    } else if (ieinfostate == false) {
        ieinfostate = true;
        server.logMessage("Please close Internet Explorer first. This installer will wait till its closed.");
    }
}, 500);

var dosomethingelse = function () {
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    server.logMessage("Unpacking file");
    /* your unpack stuff here */
};
```

sadly a timer is the only way to wait for closing of a process in windows.

microsoft fails hard at implementing usefull api's like process state change events etc in jscript.

if you would like to have it clean you should consider using c, c++ or c#

Comment: Thanks alot for helping. Can you please take a look at the code again?

Comment: @user1823753: what are you trying there? you've just copied a part of my code into your question. is this all the code that your js file contains? unless you show us the full code we cannot figure out where your problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript in a browser does not have a wait function and there is no way to make one.

In your particular case, you could use a `setInterval()` call to regularly check some state every 500ms or so and then when you find the desired state, stop the interval timer and carry out some action.

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (ProcessesRunning ("iexplore.exe") == 1) {
        server.logMessage( "Please close Internet explore first" );
    } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
        var shell = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" );
        server.logMessage( "Unpacking file" );
        // ...
    }
}, 500);
```